# Make struct object thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, object, memory-management, shared-ptr

I have a function call

```
void moveMeToThread(UnsafeStruct *ptr)
{
// do stuff with ptr
}
```

Now I want to move `moveMeToThread` to a different thread, so I do not want anyone creating an object of `UnsafeStruct` on the stack and I also want memory of all `UnsafeStruct` objects made on the heap to be freed automatically. Anyone have an elegant way to do this?

Comment: _"I also want memory of all `UnsafeStruct` objects made on the heap to be freed automatically"_ - You mean, like with a smart pointer?

Comment: The heap itself is thread-safe.  What is the problem you're trying to avoid?

Comment: You tagged `shared_ptr`, so you know what that is and it seems that all you want is to replace `UnsafeStruct *ptr` with `std::shared_ptr<UnsafeStruct> ptr`. Could you clarify what other problem exactly you want to solve?

Comment: Not allowing anyone to create object on stack. @user17732522

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes a shared_ptr should do the trick but I am not able to visualise it with not allowing creation of the object on the stack.

Comment: @arielBodyLotion Why do you need to forbid that? You can't control in what storage users of a class create objects of the class type. You can (more or less) completely forbid creation of objects by making all constructors `private` and then provide a `public` static member function to create objects in the way you like, but this comes with many limitations, like the user not being able to copy/move the type, etc.

Comment: [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) might help you out. It does all of the magic you need done with as few potential pitfalls as the Standard could define. While you can automatically allocate a variable (on the stack for example) and then stuff it into a `shared_ptr` the hard way, you better provide a do-nothing deleter and ensure the allocation outlasts the pointer to it.

Comment: @user17732522 I want to forbid it because if someone creates an object on the stack and sends it on the thread, it can cause a crash(dangling pointer).

Comment: @arielBodyLotion If you use `std::shared_ptr` that cannot happen except when the user is already misusing `std::shared_ptr` and you can't protect against the user shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: This question is very ill-defined.  Please provide a [mre] and tell us what shortcomings you think it has.

Comment: `class Foo { Foo() {} public: static shared_ptr<Foo> Make() { return shared_ptr<Foo>{new Foo}; } };` The `Make` factory function combined with the private constructor means there won't be any Foo on the stack.  You may want to inherit from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: Why not accept your `UnsafeStruct` by value instead?  Then there are no memory management issues.

Comment: Try unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr.

Comment: @arielBodyLotion someone can lie to shared_ptr and say their UnsafeStruct is on the heap when it's actually on the stack, and then the program crashes, but you can't really stop them from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd like to make a heap-only class. There are many ways to force this:

- you might make private ctors (all of them!) and create a static `create()` function that returns a pointer (sometimes called named ctor)
- you might make dtor private

The latter technically does not save you from placement new to a suitable memory block, but otherwise protects from sensible coding mistakes and is way more compatible with algorithms and containers. E.g. you can still copy such an object via copy ctor outside the class, which is not possible if you make all ctors private (which is a requirement for the first version).

You might do this:

```
template<typename T>
class HeapOnly
{
public:
    T t;
    operator       T&()       { return t; }
    operator const T&() const { return t; }
private:
    ~HeapOnly();
};

void moveMeToThread(HeapOnly<UnsafeStruct> *ptr)
{ /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    HeapOnly<UnsafeStruct> *ptr =
        new HeapOnly<UnsafeStruct>{/* args to UnsafeStruct */};

    moveToThread(ptr);
}
```

Small note: there's no such thing as (call/parameter) stack in the C++ standard. It only appears in ItaniumABI (and potentially in other ABIs). Standard says ASDV (automatic storage duration variables) for what's commonly referred to as 'on the stack', but nothing prevents an implementation to allocate the memory on the stack (as long as compiler can prove that the object's lifetime cannot extend the stack unroll - this works e.g. if it's allocated before static initialization). It might be completely unimportant in your case, but in security-related codes, where buffer overflow is important, you can't strictly enforce not having objects allocated from the same stack this way (and thus it's suggested to do a runtime check) - but you can still enforce that the object is allocated via `new` (or the given static member function).

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want anyone creating an object of UnsafeStruct on the stack.

> I want to forbid it because if someone creates an object on the stack and sends it on the thread, it can cause a crash(dangling pointer)

Do you also want to prevent anybody from creating `int` variables on the stack? Because if somebody creates an `int` variable on the stack, and if they allow a reference or a pointer to it to outlive the stack frame that contains the variable, then their program could crash.

Seriously.

That problem is older than C++. That problem has existed since the very first edition of the C programming language. Every C and C++ programmer has to learn not to do that. Always have. Always will.

---

In some languages (e.g., Java, Python), No object of any kind can be allocated anywhere else except the *garbage-collected* heap. Variables can only hold references to objects, and dangling references are impossible. Programmers in those languages expect an assignment `a=b` to copy an object reference. That is, after the assignment, `a` and `b` both refer to the same object.

That's not the C++ way. C++ programmers expect that if some type `T` is publicly constructable, then they expect to be allowed to declare one wherever they want. And when they see `a=b`, they think of that assignment operator as copying a *value.* They expect that after the assignment, `a` and `b` still are two *different* objects that both have (in some sense) the same "value."

You will find more people saying positive things about your library if you design it to work in that same way.